# Adding parenthesis to aea.bst style file

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I am struggling to add a parenthesis to the reference list by editing the default `aea.bs`t style file. I believe this is where the change needs to be made:

```
FUNCTION {output.year} % writ
{  list.year empty$
  { skip$ }
  { "(" list.year ")" * ", " * write$}
  if$
}
```

But I can only produce:

> McAuley, Julian, and Alex Yang, 2016), “Addressing complex and subjective product-related queries with customer reviews,” 625–635, International World Wide Web Conferences Steering Committee.

with missing open parentheses

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried replacing `"("` with `"(" *`?

Comment: Hi Mico, I did actually, but I still get the same output as above :(